# html/css max-width not working

Tags: html, css

So I have a tooltip on tumblr and everything about the code is working except the max width, it's stuck at 75px. I've changed it to 250px and 300px and it refuses to stretch with the words in the tooltip.

Code:

```css
a[tooltip]:hover:after {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99999999;
  max-width: 300px;
  min-width: 60px;
  border: 1px solid #bababa;
  padding: 6px;
  margin: -27px 0px 0px 28px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #1a2242;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 7px;
  line-height: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: none;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04)0 2px 4px;
  opacity: 1;
  content: attr(tooltip);
  transition-duration: 0.6s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.6s;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.6s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.6s;
}

#s-m-t-tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99999999;
  max-width: 300px;
  min-width: 60px;
  border: 1px solid #bababa;
  padding: 6px;
  margin: -27px 0px 0px 28px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #1a2242;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 7px;
  line-height: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: none;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04)0 2px 4px;
  opacity: 1;
  outline: 0px solid #ddd;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<a href="#popup3" tooltip="words">Link</a>
```

Any help is appreciated and if you need more information, let me know.

Comment: Your code is working for me. When I run the code snippet the tooltip is constrained to the `max-width` you've set. I don't see the problem.

Comment: @smilebomb it works here for some reason but on tumblr itself the max-width code doesn't work ( ex: i.imgur.com/xz6oj5O.jpg ).

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't any great way to debug if it's working in one environment but not another. Provide a link, that's the best you can do.

Answer (score 0):

add `width: 100%;` for your pseudo element, also you can use `box-sizing`  so that the width and height properties set the dimensions of the content rather than the content.
`

```css
a[tooltip]:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99999999;
  max-width: 300px;
  min-width: 60px;
  border: 1px solid #bababa;
  padding: 6px;
  margin: -5px 0 0 28px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #1a2242;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 7px;
  line-height: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: none;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04)0 2px 4px;
  opacity: 1;
  content: attr(tooltip);
  transition-duration: 0.6s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.6s;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.6s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.6s;
}

#s-m-t-tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99999999;
  width: 300px;
  max-width: 200px;
  min-width: 60px;
  border: 1px solid #bababa;
  padding: 6px;
  margin: -27 0 0 28px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #1a2242;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 7px;
  line-height: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: none;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04)0 2px 4px;
  opacity: 1;
  outline: 0px solid #ddd;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<a href="#popup3" tooltip="words hooha haooo ahhahhhah ahahhahhah ahahhahaha hahahhahha ahahahhahha ahahhaha">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's not working is because you have a `width:100%` set on the `a:after` pseudo-element. That property will set the width of the element to that of it's parent, in this case your `a` is a child of your `<div class="markericon1">`. You can see that if you change just the width of `<div class="markericon1">` to something higher you will get the result you want.

```
.markericon1 {
    width:300px;
}
```